# Core Animation with contentsRect jerkiness

Tags: iphone, core-animation

in my (puzzle) game the pieces are drawn on-screen using a `CALayer` for each piece. There are 48 pieces (in an 8x6 grid) with each piece being 48x48 pixels. I'm not sure if this is just too many layers, but if this isn't the best solution I don't know what is, because redrawing the whole display using Quartz2D every frame doesn't seem like it would be any faster.

Anyway, the images for the pieces come from one big PNG file that has 24 frames of animation for 10 different states (so measures 1152 x 480 pixels) and the animation is done by setting the `contentsRect` property of each `CALayer` as I move it.

This actually seems to work pretty well with up to 7 pieces tracking a touch point in the window, but the weird thing is that when I initially start moving the pieces, for the first 0.5 a second or so, it's very jerky like the CPU is doing something else, but after that it'll track and update the screen at 40+ FPS (according to Instruments).

So does anyone have any ideas what could account for that initial jerkiness?

The only theory I could come up with is it's decompressing bits of the PNG file into a temporary location and then discarding them after the animation has stopped, in which case is there a way to stop Core Animation doing that?

I could obviously split the PNG file up into 10 pieces, but I'm not convinced that would help as they'd all (potentially) still need to be in memory at once.

**EDIT:** OK, as described in the comment to the first answer, I've split the image up into ten pieces that are now 576 x 96, so as to fit in with the constraints of the hardware. It's still not as smooth as it should be though, so I've put a bounty on this.

**EDIT2:** I've linked one of the images below. Essentially the user's touch is tracked, the offset from the start of the tracking is calculated (they can one move horizontal or vertical and only one place at a time). Then one of the images is selected as the content of the layer (depending on what type of piece it is and whether it's moving horizontally or vertically). Then the `contentsRect` property is set to chose one 48x48 frame from the larger image with something like this:-

```
layer.position = newPos;
layer.contents = (id)BallImg[imgNum];
layer.contentsRect = CGRectMake((1.0/12.0)*(float)(frame % 12), 
                                0.5 * (float)(frame / 12), 
                                1.0/12.0, 0.5);
```

btw. My theory about it decompressing the source image a-fresh each time wasn't right. I wrote some code to copy the raw pixels from the decoded PNG file into a fresh `CGImage` when the app loads and it didn't make any difference.

Next thing I'll try is copying each frame into a separate `CGImage` which will get rid of the ugly `contentsRect` calculation at least.

[image: Sample image]

**EDIT3:** Further back-to-basics investigation points to this being a problem with touch tracking and not a problem with Core Animation at all. I found a basic sample app that tracks touches and commented out the code that actually causes the screen to redraw and the `NSLog()` shows the exactly the same problem I've been experiencing: A long-ish delay between the `touchesBegin` and first `touchesMoved` events.

```
2009-06-05 01:22:37.209 TouchDemo[234:207] Begin Touch ID 0 Tracking with image 2
2009-06-05 01:22:37.432 TouchDemo[234:207] Touch ID 0 Tracking with image 2
2009-06-05 01:22:37.448 TouchDemo[234:207] Touch ID 0 Tracking with image 2
2009-06-05 01:22:37.464 TouchDemo[234:207] Touch ID 0 Tracking with image 2
2009-06-05 01:22:37.480 TouchDemo[234:207] Touch ID 0 Tracking with image 2
```

Typical gap between `touchesMoved` events is 20ms. The gap between the `touchesBegin` and first `touchesMoved` is ten times that. And that's with no computation or screen updating at all, just the `NSLog` call. Sigh. I guess I'll open this up a separate question.

Comment: When you say: "Anyway, the images for the pieces come from one big PNG file that has 24 frames of animation for 10 different states (so measures 1152 x 480 pixels) and the animation is done by setting the contentsRect property of each CALayer as I move it."

Are you trying to animate the image on each piece? Are you animating to different images OR to a different rect of the original large image? 

Are you just chopping up an image and placing the smaller images on individual layers to be moved around? Are you doing anything else while moving the layer?

Comment: Can you check if you are running any other code when you touch a tile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's a memory issue; I'm thinking that it has to do with the inefficiency of having that large of an image in terms of Core Animation.

Core Animation can't use it natively, as it exceeds the maximum texture size on the GPU (1024x1024). **I would break it up some**; individual images might give you the best performance, but you'll have to test to find out.

IIRC, UIImageView does its animating by setting successive individual images, so if it's good enough for Apple….

Comment: After some refactoring, I broke the image up so now there are 10 images, each with the 24 frames and then those images are split into two rows to make the dimensions 576 x 96. And it's certainly a lot faster than before. There is still some jerkiness when starting to animate though.

I'm still suspecting that Core Animation is discarding the decompressed PNG after it's copied out the section that it wants to display. I can't see any other reason why it would animate smoothly when it gets going, but have a delay after the display is static for some time.

Answer (score 1):

When it is about performance, I definitly recommend using Shark (also over Instruments). In the 'Time Profile' you can see what are the bottlenecks in your app, even if it is something in Apple's code. I used it a lot while developing my iPhone app that uses OpenGL and Core Animation.

Comment: I played about with instruments a bit, not tried shark yet. The problem I have is that I'm only concerned with what happens immediately after my view gets a TouchesBegin event because the application isn't doing anything outside of the TouchesBegin/TouchesMoved/TouchesEnd sequence and all that idle time makes averages a bit meaningless. Is there any way you can enable/disable collection in your code?

Comment: That's exactly why Shark is better suited for this task than Instruments: Instruments does not distinguish between idle and active CPU but Shark does.
This means, you can profile for 10 seconds, manually activating your code (by tapping a button or whatever) a couple of times. The profile Shark produces only shows the samples where the CPU was actually doing something. If you further narrow down the code paths by selecting your main thread only you can easily see what's going on in your code.

Comment: About programmatically enabling Shark: There has been the CHUD.framework in MacOS 10.4 but it has been made private in 10.5. It never existed for iPhone OS as far as I know. There's a way of controlling a remote profiling session using signals (see man shark), but I don't know if that's working on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using CATiledLayer yet?

It is optimized for this type of work.

Comment: AFAIK CATiledLayer is for the opposite case - that of creating one really large layer (> 1024x1024) from lots of separately drawn tiles.

Comment: Hmmm. I think I misunderstood what you are trying to accomplish, could you provide some more info (I commented some questions to your original question)