# Pass all the events of a UIGestureRecognizer from one UIView to another UIView (subview)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIView with gesture recognizers attached to it.

In some cases (for instance tapping in a certain area) I would like to pass the tap to the sub view.

The sub view's user interaction is disabled (because I don't want it to receive swipes for instance).

In the cases I would like it to receive the event - how can this be achieved.

Comment: Sorry Avner, it's not good SO-tiquette to ask the same question [twice in the same day](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20889713/1375695)

Comment: Its in a different language - for clarity sake. Maybe the first explination isn't clear . I really just want an answer

Comment: If you find your original question is unclear you should edit it to make it clearer, not start a new one (unless it is for a new issue).

Comment: Duplicating your question discourages anyone writing a considered response. Please be patient - good answers rarely arrive quickly.

Comment: Your earlier question should be edited to clarify or expand if necessary, rather than a second question created.

Answer (score 0):

here's code for handling gesture events.

```
 UIPanGestureRecognizer * moveGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                        initWithTarget:self
                                     action:@selector(onMove:)];
 [moveGesture setDelegate:self];
```

add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to your view class delegates and then implement such function:

```
- (void) onMove:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
 switch (gesture.state) {
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
    {
         //handle the events here
         //and don't forget if you want to your view receive touches
         //userInteraction must be enabled.

         //if you want to get touch in your super view you just do this:
         CGPoint pointToSuperview = [gesture locationInView:self.superview];
         //this is the point where touch is received to your superview 
    }
        break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
    {

    }
        break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed:
    {

    }
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
}
```

Comment: that doesn't answer my question at all!