# How do I get a mobile browser to not introduce a 100s msec delay with Javascript touch events?

Tags: javascript, mobile, web-applications, touch, delay

My understanding is that mobile browsers used to purposefully introduce 300 ms delays with touch events. It was some means to allow for double-clicks and not found with mouse events. Supposedly this was removed around 2014.

However, I am clearly seeing/recording a delay on this order of 100s of milliseconds. This in my web app for both Chrome and Safari. No issue when using a desktop browser. Also, switching the mobile browser to desktop mode seems to remedy the situation. I'd like to avoid users from having to do this.

Has anyone else had this issue? Do you have a solution?

I tried adding this per an old solution but it did not fix it.

Comment: [This](http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/fast-touch-event-handling-eliminate-click-delay.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259183/delay-with-touch-events) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This old solution seems to have worked

```
html {
    touch-action: manipulation;
}
```

I inserted it into my div style for the concerning section.

Seems to have worked for Chrome and Safari. Odd since: 1) as of 2014 this was not supposed to be an issue anymore, and 2) the solution supposedly didn't work with Safari when originally proposed.

FYI - Here's the link for the solutions that I tried.

https://developer.chrome.com/blog/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away/